# Batch file setting variable in if/else statement in For Loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that generates a custom AVIsynth script per each file. Right now the batch file is set to execute from within the folder where the video files exist. What I need to do is get the creation time of the file to generate a timecode burn in. I have no problem getting the info I need. However, if the file was created in the afternoon I need it to be in 24hr time. For example, 2pm needs to display as 14.

I have a working if statement that creates a `newth` variable that adds 12 if need be. However, if it doesn't need it the variable persists. On each subsequent iteration of the loop the variable doesn't change.

My example. I have two files the first was created at 2pm the other at 12pm. The 2pm file is read first and the `newth` variable becomes 14. So far so good. On the next file the `newth` variable should become 12 but instead remains 14. How do I fix this?

```
@Echo Off & CLS
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F %%a In ('dir *.mpg /b') Do (
    ECHO Processing "%%a"
    echo %%~ta
    set time=%%~ta
    set th=!time:~11,2!
    set tm=!time:~14,2!
    set era=!time:~17,2!
    echo !era!
    if "!era!"=="PM" (
        if !th! LSS 12 ( set /a newth=!th!+12 )
    ) else ( set /a newth=!th!)

    echo !newth!
    echo //AviSynth Test Script >scripts/%%a.avs
    echo DirectshowSource^("%%~fa"^)>>scripts/%%a.avs
    echo LanczosResize^(720,400^) >>scripts/%%a.avs
    echo ShowSMPTE^(^) >>scripts/%%a.avs

    ECHO Back to Console
    Pause
)
```

It's a little messy because I've been using `echo` for debugging. But hopefully the problem is clear.

Comment: have you tried with `if /i "!era!" == "PM"`

Comment: thanks but that doesn't solve the problem I'm having. The issue is that if `newth` exists from a previous loop it wont switch back to `!th!` in the else section. Thus, keeping its value from a previous iteration.

Comment: what is your OS? There are few more ways to get the time...

Comment: aaah...set `set "th="` at the begining of the loop to clear it's value

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. I just figured out that setting the OS time to 24hr solves the problem. I would however like to get the file modified time down to the second but can only get cmd to display hours and minutes.

Comment: `%%~ta` doesn't display seconds. `dir` also doesn't. You can set the system time format to whatever.

Comment: did you want modified time or creation time?  You have mentioned both.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method with Wmic - Wmic is in XP pro and above.

```
@Echo Off & CLS
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "delims=" %%a In ('dir *.mpg /b') Do (
    ECHO Processing "%%a"

    set "file=%cd%\%%a"
    set "file=!file:\=\\!"
    WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="!file!" get creationdate|find ".">file.tmp
    for /f %%a in (file.tmp) do set dt=%%a
    set tm=!dt:~8,2!:!dt:~10,2!:!dt:~12,2!
    del file.tmp
    echo !tm!
    echo //AviSynth Test Script >scripts/%%a.avs
    echo DirectshowSource^("%%~fa"^)>>scripts/%%a.avs
    echo LanczosResize^(720,400^) >>scripts/%%a.avs
    echo ShowSMPTE^(^) >>scripts/%%a.avs

    ECHO Back to Console
    Pause
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code. The major one is this sequence

```
if "!era!"=="PM" (
    if !th! LSS 12 ( set /a newth=!th!+12 )
) else ( set /a newth=!th!)
```

With your first filetime "02:xx PM"
`th`=02, `era`=PM, so `set /a newth=02+12` sets `newth`=14

With your second filetime "12:xx PM"
`th`=12, `era`=PM, so - do nothing, since there's no `else` action for `!th! LSS 12`

Hence, `newth` remains at 14.

So - what's the fix? Since you don't use `newth` further, we can't say for certain, but it appears you want 24-hour format - 4 digit `hhmm`.

**DANGER, Will Robinson** moment number 1:
You are dealing with numbers starring LEADING ZEROES. All well and good except where the value is `08` or `09`, which batch bizarrely interprets as OCTAL since it begins `0`.

**DANGER, Will Robinson** moment number 2:
`set /a` will suppress leading zeroes, so `set /a newth=!th!` will set `newth` to `7` for time `07:36 AM` - not `07`...

So - how to overcome all this?

```
IF !th!==12 SET th=00
SET th=!th: =0!
if "!era!"=="PM" (set /a newth=1!th!+12
 SET newth=!newth:~-2!
) else ( set newth=!th!)
```

This forces `12 AM` to `00 AM` and `12 PM` to `00 PM`
Then replace any `spaces` with `0` (in case you have leading spaces, not zeroes)
Then, if `era` is `PM`, add 100 by stringing `1` before the `2-digit` hour number, add 12 and grab the last 2 characters
Otherwise, just use the number in `th`

Unfortunately, made a little more complicated since you haven't told us whether you use or don't use leading zeroes in your time format. Nevertheless, the incomplete original calculation method is at fault.

**DANGER, Will Robinson** moment number 3:
`time` is a **MAGIC VARIABLE** - and you know [what happened to Mickey](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSTWy25hRiI) when he got involved in things better left alone.

If you set `time` in a batch, then `%time%` or `!time!` will return the value you set. If you don't set it, then the value returned will be the system time. Same goes for `DATE` and a number of similar values (see `set /?` from the prompt - there's a list at the end)

Answer (score 0):

here's how you can get the time stamp with seconds:

```
C:\>powershell -command "& {(gwmi -query """select * from cim_datafile where name = 'C:\\file.txt' """).lastModified;}"

C:\>powershell -command "& {(gwmi -query """select * from cim_datafile where name = 'D:\\other.txt' """).creationdate;}"
```

I've tried with `WMIC` but still cannot get the time stamp.As you are using Win7 you should have powershell installed by default.